# iMovie Crashing for a particular Project

Tags: crash, macbook, imovie

I have a working iMovie library. All the projects in it are working and I can open them except one particular project. This project was also working fine but then I copied one emoji in a title and then it crashed. After this, as soon as I try to open/share/duplicate the project, the iMovie crashes.

I have already tried to access the project from other login user account. Following are the top few lines of the error report.

```
    Process:               iMovie [1334]
Path:                  /Applications/iMovie.app/Contents/MacOS/iMovie
Identifier:            iMovie
Version:               10.1.11 (342230)
App Item ID:           408981434
App External ID:       830553401
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           iMovie [1334]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-04-13 20:38:33.305 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.3 (18D109)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        131CFF0A-CE7B-5175-696E-85C0C8D10B1E


Time Awake Since Boot: 780 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: NSManagedObjectContext 0x600002a50870

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1334]

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(duplicateProject:) from sender NSMenuItem 0x6000070167c0
∏  £ˇ
```

Answer (score -1):

Ouch. Access violation. That's a big bad bug in the iMovie code, nothing of your doing. To be reported to Apple, if there is any way. Other people might know if there are workarounds, but I don't.